# Publish comments to Facebook User Wall and Facebook Fan Page

Tags: php, facebook-wall, facebook-comments

I am developing a website and I have a question about Facebook integration:

When a person makes a comment on my website, I would like the comment to be posted to the person's Facebook wall **and** the wall of a Facebook fan page.

If I'm not mistaken, this is done through "FACEBOOK COMMENTS" right?

This publishes to the wall of the person commenting, but, on the wall of the fan page, nothing is published.  Why?

Thanks and best regards!

Javier

Answer (score 0):

Post to the fan page, then if the user has it setup, it will show up in their wall... but again the user has complete control over this... they can hide, delete, or remove access to the page and it completely changes how it shows or if it shows on their wall.